# S/N ratio or distortion analyzer

Tags: audio, signal-to-noise, total-harmonic-distortion

I'm having trouble finding an affordable low bandwidth analyzer solution for measuring audio spectrum performance (20KHz and below).  Does anyone have a suggestion for buying (new / used) or building a s/n ratio meter or distortion analyzer for comparing components at a line level output of 5V pk-pk 1Mohm or less?

Comment: So just the spectrum and distortion?  There are free tools (RMAA) for doing this with just a sound card and PC.

Comment: audacity does it free....

Comment: 5 Vpp is too much for a PC's line input so use a resistive divider or a volume control potmeter (these are logarithmic for nice volume control). So attenuate the signal, feed into a PC's line input (get a cheap USB external soundcard/stick if your PC doesn't have a line input) and as suggested, use Audacity which is freeware.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie 5Vpp may or may not be too high. Many consumer devices can support the 2Vrms level which is about 5.6Vpp. And surely a slightly more expensive audio interface for connecting mics/guitars/synths can handle such levels easily out of the box, including the gain knob.

Comment: to 20 kHz, all you need is a PC and a sound card. Plenty of free options for analysis, or use python+portaudio+numpy+matplotlib to roll your own. That's what I did a decade ago in a professional capacity, nothing was available at any price on the open market to do what I needed to do with some audio signals.

Comment: I don't know why there's not an option for me to mark this as solved.  I appreciate the answers from all of you.